# Android: Using two different Adapters for a Gridview grid

Tags: android, gridview, android-arrayadapter, android-image

I was wondering if it is possible to apply two different Adapters (ArrayAdapter for a String array, and ImageAdapter for the background of each value in the array) for a certain 4X4 dimension grid… I ask this because my actual (the code below is just a sample) program contains user-inputted values for height and width (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382979/android-auto-fitting-row-height-of-gridview-based-on-user-inputted-values) as opposed to hardcoding. Say, if I wanted to assign the brown blocks as a background for the odd numbers, and the gray blocks for the even numbers using grid.setAdapter() for both Adapters... How would I code that using Android Studio?

Here's the following Java code for the grid:

```
package dpark.sample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int height, width;
    String[] list;
    GridView grid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        height = 4;
        width = 4;

        buildList();

        grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setNumColumns(width);

        //***TEMPORARILY COMMENTING THE FOLLOWING OUT SINCE THIS WILL JUST OVERWRITE THE
        // ARRAYADAPTER***
        //grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
    }

    private void buildList() {
        int tempIncrementor = 1;
        int dimensions = height * width;

        list = new String[dimensions];

        for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
            list[i] = String.valueOf(tempIncrementor);

            tempIncrementor++;
        }
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            return imageView;
        }

        // references to our images
        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.brownblock,
                R.drawable.grayblock
        };
    }
}
```

... Which outputs in the virtual emulator:

[image]

... As for outputting the color block images, I temporarily commented out the ArrayAdapter blocks in my code so I could output the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't set two adapters beacuse the method setAdapter overrides the previous one.

But your goal doesn't require it, you should store the values in arraylist and retrieve them in the getView method.